# WKWebView in UITableViewCustomCell the view.frame is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have 4 cells in my project every cell have the same class HtmlCell, in this case the view return nil, the following code:

```
class HtmlCell: UITableViewCell{

    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var billboard: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: LabelDeviceClass!
    @IBOutlet weak var redactorImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var redactorName: LabelDeviceClass!
    @IBOutlet weak var redactorDescripcion: LabelDeviceClass!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
    }  
}
```

This line return nil because the view.frame is nil:

```
self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
```

Now I put the cell of Wkwebview a new class exampleCell with the following code:

```
class ExampleCell: UITableViewCell {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
    }
}
```

For my surprise the view.frame is not nil and work perfectly. Which is the problem in the before code.

Any Help?

Comment: Is self.view itself not nil in the first code?

Comment: Layout should be implemented by overriding `layoutSubviews`. Better yet, use auto-layout, or `autoresizingMask`.  See: "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews"

Comment: One more thing to account for is that subviews of a UITableViewCell should all be children of `contentView`. Subviews should never be added to the cell view directly.

Comment: First code self.view is nil

Comment: Luke but the wkwebview is added to self.view is not added directly to the cell